# Finding distances between point and line?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The problem:

Compute the distance *d* from *y* to the line through *u* and the origin.

$$\vec y = \begin{pmatrix} 
-1   \\
5   \\
7  
\end{pmatrix},\ \vec u = \begin{pmatrix} 
-2   \\
-2   \\
4  
\end{pmatrix}$$

My solution:

So I know the formula

$$ \vec d = \left\lvert \vec y -  \frac{\mathrm{\vec y}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec u}} {\left\lVert \vec u \right\rVert} \vec u\right\rvert$$

computes vector $\vec d$ that is the shortest vector between $\vec y$ and $\vec u$. When I use this formula, I get

$$\vec d = \begin{pmatrix} 
-1 + \frac{20}{\sqrt 6}   \\
5 + \frac{20}{\sqrt 6} \\
7  - \frac{40}{\sqrt 6}
\end{pmatrix}$$

which has a magnitude of about 17.66. This is wrong and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance :)

Comment: Title says distance between vectors, but body concerns distance between point and line. Please edit for consistency. Also, if you're not sure *why* it's wrong, how are you sure *that* it's wrong? Also note that if you multiply $u$ by $2$, that will not change the line, but it will change the value your formula gives for $d$. This suggests your formula's wrong.

Comment: You should have $|\vec u|^2$ in the denominator. You can check the validity of the formula by taking the scalar product of $\vec d$ and $\vec u$, which should be $0$.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!